# Grouping list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
x = [('y', [1, 2]), ('y', [3, 4]), ('y', [5, 6])]
```

And I want to return me something like this:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Note: the tuple number can vary, may be also:

```
x = [('y', [1, 2, 3, 4]), ('y', [5, 6, 7, 8]), ('y', [9, 10, 11, 12]), ('y', [13, 14, 15, 16])]
```

which would produce

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11, 12), (13, 14, 15, 16)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to get the second item of each element:

```
new_list = [tuple(b) for a, b in old_list]
```

Comment: Please be sure to mark as answer with the check mark beside my answer.